# Disable / turn off LiveReload server in Emberjs / Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, livereload

I use Cloud9 IDE, which only exposes port 80 and prevents LiveReload from connecting. I get this error:

> GET https://myapp.c9.io:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Unless someone knows of a fix, I'd like to simply turn this feature off / disable it.

I'm running Ember-cli and I can see the task in ember-cli/lib/tasks/serve.js and I've commented it out, but it didn't do the trick:

```
/*
    var liveReloadServer = new LiveReloadServer({
      ui: this.ui,
      analytics: this.analytics,
      watcher: watcher
    });
*/
```

It's buried in enough places that I'm afraid to npm remove it, as I think that would just create bigger problems.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should be able to disable live reload by starting your sever like this:

`ember server --live-reload=false`

Answer (score 15):

With the addition of the .ember-cli config file, you can just add `"liveReload": false` to it.
[Example](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1080) '.ember-cli' file

```
{
"port": 9999,
"host": "0.0.0.0",
"liveReload": false,
"proxy": "http://aqueous-bayou-5108.herokuapp.com/",
"environment": "development"
}
```

Edit: `live-reload` was changed to `liveReload` in this [commit](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/5d3f1bf8f5d36ae7585843fd29db311a41d513c5)

Comment: Note, the correct format is `liveReload` (with camelCase)

Comment: Good catch. Updated the post with `liveReload`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Dhaulagiri's answer, you can use:

`ember server -lr false`
or
`ember s -lr false`

For all the options:

`ember help server`