# Ember cli server option to rebuild on demand

Tags: ember-cli

Whenever I change any file in my ember-cli app, ember-cli starts to rebuild application. Rebuilding takes time approx (30 sec). I have to wait 30 secs every time I make any small change in any file.

Is there option to rebuild when I want ?, may passing an option to `ember server` command and restart server when I press 'r' or 'R'.

I am not using outdated machine, so I think its not my machine issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026796/disable-turn-off-livereload-server-in-emberjs-ember-cli

Comment: @AcidBurn Thanks for link , but its not what I am looking for. I want to control live reload and not turn it off.